# can't open file 'conda': [Errno 2] No such file or directory on PyCharm on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I got this error while running the code on PyCharm 2018 on mac
May anyone help me please?

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'conda': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Running what code? Were you intending to use a conda environment to run Python?

Comment: I was running a simple python code and I wanted conda environment to run Python

Comment: Did you configure PyCharm to use the conda environment, and if so how?